# How to tell if time sync in VirtualBox is working

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, sync

I have a VirtualBox setup like this:
HOST:  Windows XP
GUEST : Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop without GUI (command line only)

I had some problems with time sync as my guest was frequently going out of sync.
After a failed attempt to address this issue using ntp, i read that the guest-additions could sync time between host and guest.

I installed virtualbox-guest-additions ,virtualbox-guest-dpkg and virtualbox-guest-utils, and after restart, the guest ubuntu did in fact syncronize with the host.
**Note: I did not install guest-additions from the ISO provided by virtualbox**

But how can i be sure that time sync is in fact working due to the guest additions?
Is there any tool to run from host or guest to check that time sync service is installed?

Thanks in advance!